# What is happening with this picture alignment in internet explorer? (ie and egde)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello wonderful people of the internet,

I am having a problem with a website that I am building. 
I am seeing some strange behavior with aligning an image in the center of an element while also applying a smooth "move upwards" animation.

It is perfectly centered in chrome, but not in internet explorer and edge.

I think this has to do with setting the CSS property, `top: 0;`. Because if I do that, it isn't centered in Chrome aswell.

Here is the jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/p4souo8d/2/

```js
// project div animation on hover
$(".project").bind({
  mouseenter: function() {
    var image = $(this).find(".project-inner img"), projectInner = $(this).find(".project-inner");
    var bottomMargin = (projectInner.height() - image.height()) / 2;
    projectInner.fadeIn(400);
    image.animate({ bottom: Math.round(bottomMargin) }, 300);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).find(".project-inner").fadeOut(200).promise().done(function(){
      $(this).find("img").css({
        bottom: 0
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.project {
    width: 360px;
    height: 260px;
    background-color: #2C3E50;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    position: relative
}
.project .project-inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #3498DB;
    display: none
}
.project .project-inner img {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/360/260/" alt="" />
  <div class="project-inner">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Meer informatie" />
    <div class="project-information">
      Hello there! :)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Sorry about the pictures, they are randomly generated.

Comment: No worries. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
.project .project-inner img {
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Can you explain to me what the fault was?

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: I think that problem was with `margin:auto` in IE the image was centered in the middle of the div. By omitting margin-top property now it is centered in the bottom:)

Comment: You can do `margin:0 auto;` too since it is a little shorter, i have edited my answer hope it helps...